# Can I insert a statement into an empty function body using a Roslyn DocumentEditor

Tags: visual-studio, roslyn

In my Visual Studio extension, I am using the DocumentEditor (Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editing.DocumentEditor) class to make multiple updates to a source file.

One of the changes it to add a constructor to a class. The constructor must have a specific parameter, which is passed in by dependency injection, and must save the parameter to a member variable.
If the constructor is already present, it should check for the parameter and check for the assignment statement.

Most of this is working, but there is a problem if I have to add a statement to an empty function.

If the constructor already exists and contains some statements, I can add a new statement with

```
RoslynEditor.InsertBefore ( cons.Body.Statements.First(), assExpr ) ;
```

If the constructor exists, but is empty, then this won't work. So far I haven't found any way to insert a statement into an empty function body using the DocumentEditor class.

At present, I have opted for the sledge hammer method of replacing the complete constructor using DocumentEditor.ReplaceNode.

**So is there a way to insert a statement into the body of a function - using the DocumentEditor class - if the body is empty?**

Here is part of my code. 
The functions in _RoslynUtilCS just return some roslyn syntax.

```
// Look for the constructor
var cons = c.DescendantNodes().OfType<ConstructorDeclarationSyntax>().FirstOrDefault() ;
if ( cons == null )
{
  // There is no constructor.
  cons = _RoslynUtilCS.ControllerConstructor ( ShortClassName )
                      .WithAdditionalAnnotations ( Formatter.Annotation )
                      .WithTrailingTrivia ( _RoslynUtilCS.LineFeedSyntax() ) ;

  RoslynEditor.InsertBefore ( c.Members.First(), cons ) ;
}
else
{
  string parameterName = null ;

  // There is a constructor.
  // Does it already have a parameter of the generic IStringLocalizer type
  foreach ( var p in cons.ParameterList.Parameters )
  {
    var t  = p.Type ;
    var gt = t as GenericNameSyntax ;
    if ( gt != null )
    {
      if ( gt.Identifier.ToString() == "IStringLocalizer" )
      {
        parameterName = p.Identifier.ToString() ;
      }
    }
  }

  if ( string.IsNullOrEmpty ( parameterName ) )
  {
    // Add a parameter
    var param = _RoslynUtilCS.LocalizerParameter ( ShortClassName ) ;
    RoslynEditor.AddParameter ( cons, param ) ;

    // Add an assignment statement to assign the parameter to the localizer member variable.
    var assExpr = _RoslynUtilCS.LocalizerAsignment()
                               .WithAdditionalAnnotations ( Formatter.Annotation ) ;

    if ( cons.Body.Statements.Count == 0 )
    {
      // -------------------------------------------------------------------
      // Here I replace the complete constructor.
      // because I don't know how to insert a statement into
      // the empty constructor body.
      // -------------------------------------------------------------------
      var newcons = _RoslynUtilCS.ControllerConstructor ( ShortClassName )
                                 .WithAdditionalAnnotations ( Formatter.Annotation )
                                 .WithTrailingTrivia ( _RoslynUtilCS.LineFeedSyntax() ) ;

      RoslynEditor.ReplaceNode ( cons, newcons ) ;
    }
    else
    {
      RoslynEditor.InsertBefore ( cons.Body.Statements.First(), assExpr ) ;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    // NOT TESTED
    // It seems a bit over the top, but having found a parameter, we should look
    // for an assignment to the member variable and add it if it is missing.
    var count = cons.DescendantNodes()
                    .OfType<AssignmentExpressionSyntax>()
                    .Where(node => node.Kind() == SyntaxKind.SimpleAssignmentExpression)
                    .Where(node => node.Left.ToString() == "_localizer")
                    .Where(node => node.Right.ToString() == "localizer")
                    .Count() ;
    if ( count == 0 )
    {
      // Add an assignment statement to assign the parameter to the localizer member variable.
      var assExpr = _RoslynUtilCS.LocalizerAsignment() ;

      // -------------------------------------------------------------------
      // This is likely to have the same problem.
      // It won't work if the body contains no statements.
      // -------------------------------------------------------------------
      RoslynEditor.InsertBefore ( cons.Body.Statements.First(), assExpr ) ;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Insert` and `Add` method of the editor are finally `InsertMembers` of `SyntaxGenerator` and they anyway replacing the original node with new one AKA `Replace`.

Check the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/4f95434c889d468821620da86ddce87756255b16/src/Workspaces/CSharp/Portable/CodeGeneration/CSharpSyntaxGenerator.cs#L1370) of this method and you will see that inserting members to block body with 0 members (in case of `ConstructorDeclarationSyntax`) is return the declaration itself without change, this why you can't do simple `editor.Insert\Add..`.

You can define a new extension method that does it for you or writing something like this that replacing just the body:

```
editor.ReplaceNode(ctor.Body, SyntaxFactory.Block(newStatement));
```

Or

```
editor.ReplaceNode(ctor, ctor.WithBody(ctor.Body.AddStatements(newStatement)));
```

Comment: Just to understand the source code: if the switch statement in InsertMembers had a **case SyntaxKind.Block:** implemented almost exactly like the other cases, then I could use the InsertMembers method on the DocumentEditor class.  
Anyway, replacing the body works and I think it is a better solution than replacing the complete constructor.

Comment: @PhilJollans Not exactly, because `BlockSyntax` is not a declaration. But if `existingMembers.Count > 0` it was work. Or if the `switch` had a case for constructor and constructor had a method `WithMembers`.